# Analysis of circuit with dependent voltage source with no apparent solution

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, nodal-analysis, mesh-analysis

This is an exercise from Irwin's book, 9th edition.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftaMab.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Although the book calls for the use of nodal analysis, I decided to do it by mesh analysis (this is what I am currently training).

The question asks for the value of V<sub>C</sub>. After performing Mesh Analysis, I arrived at the matrix equation:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 &-3  &-1 \\ 
-1 &2  &0 \\ 
-1 &0  &2 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
i_A\\ 
i_B\\ 
i_C
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
-12m\\ 
12m
\end{pmatrix}$$

Whose determinant is zero.

When I found a solution book on the internet, performing a nodal analysis, I arrived at the value of V<sub>C</sub> = 9 V. However, when performing the Super Node Equation, it considers V<sub>C</sub> - V<sub>A</sub> = 2·k·I<sub>1</sub>, which does not seem correct to me.

Anyway, am I wrong in assuming that there is no solution for this circuit? In case there is no such solution, what explanation could I have for this?

Thinking about the idea of building a circuit, it bothers me a bit that they don't have a solution. Is this due to the topological restrictions imposed by Kirchhoff's Law and Ohm's Law? Or is it a flaw in the theory trying to describe a real physical system?

Is my assembly in the simulator correct? In particular, how to realize the current-controlled voltage source?

Comment: Is that "R1.nA" really just I(R1)? And if so, which direction is considered positive? I don't understand the notation, I guess. Also, what's the point of nodes **B** and **D**? They are defined as 0 V. So I don't know why you placed them there. (And no, I don't have Irwin's book on hand.)

Comment: In fact, I agree that there is no need to indicate nodes B and D. As for the notation, I understand that R1.nA indicates the current going from node A towards resistor R1, in this case, the current that controls the voltage source is the one "going down" from node A towards GND.

Comment: So is [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/862UK.png) an accurate representation?

Comment: Exactly. I had just made the changes. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Seems to solve out okay. Do you already have the answer from using a nodal approach? Okay. *Well, never mind that!* It solves out symbolically. But when the numbers are plugged in, then I think you may be right. I need to double check my work.

Comment: In your analysis, is my matrix wrong?
As for having a Nodal Analysis solution, yes... I have one that gives \$V_C = 9V\$ but it seems to me to have an error, as I put in the question, that would be to consider \$-V_C+V_A = 2k i_1\$.

Answer (score 3):

Adapting your diagram, here's how I'd plan out the mesh analysis:

[image]

$$\begin{align*}
0\:\text{V} + V_1 -\left(I_1-I_3\right)R_2 - I_1 \,R_1 &= 0\:\text{V}
\\\\
0\:\text{V} - I_2 \,R_4 -\left(I_2-I_3\right)R_3-V_1&= 0\:\text{V}
\\\\
0\:\text{V} -\left(I_3-I_1\right)R_2 -\left(I_3-I_2\right)R_3+I_1\,R_{_\text{CCVS}}&=0\:\text{V}
\end{align*}$$

So the matrix I get is:

$$\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
-R_1-R_2&0&R_2
\\\\
0 & - R_3 -R_4 &R_3
\\\\
R_2+R_{_\text{CCVS}}&R_3&-R_2 -R_3
\end{smallmatrix}\right]\left[\begin{smallmatrix}I_1\\\\I_2\\\\I_3\end{smallmatrix}\right]=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}-V_1\vphantom{I_1}\\\\V_1\vphantom{I_1}\\\\0\vphantom{I_1}\end{smallmatrix}\right]$$

Or, dividing everything though by 1,000 and stuffing in values:

$$\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
-2&0&1\vphantom{I_1}
\\\\
0 & -2 &1\vphantom{I_1}
\\\\
3&1&-2\vphantom{I_1}
\end{smallmatrix}\right]\left[\begin{smallmatrix}I_1\\\\I_2\\\\I_3\end{smallmatrix}\right]=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}-12\:\text{m}\vphantom{I_1}\\\\12\:\text{m}\vphantom{I_1}\\\\0\vphantom{I_1}\end{smallmatrix}\right]$$

Signs different but the gist is the same.

For nodal analysis, I'd start here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9ZAAk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But \$I_{R_1}=\frac{V_{_\text{A}}}{R_1}\$ so it follows that the voltage difference across the current controlled voltage source must be \$2\cdot V_{_\text{A}}\$. But this means that \$V_{_\text{C}}=-V_{_\text{A}}\$.

And, using Thevenin equivalents I find:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVOeKQ.png)</sup>

And there, the current must be the same throughout. But it cannot be the same throughout. So it cannot be resolved by nodal, either.

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion to do it generically, I took R<sub>1</sub> = R.

Then the Mesh Analysis equations are:

\$2i_A-3i_B-i_C=0\$

\$-i_A+(R+1)i_B=-12\$

\$-i_A+2i_C=12\$

With \$i_A\$, \$i_B\$ and \$i_C\$ being the loop currents.

From the second and third equation, I put \$i_B\$ and \$i_C\$ as a function of \$i_A\$, substituting in the first equation and solving, I get:

\$i_A = (25+R)/(R-1)\$

Therefore, the system has no solution the way it is described in the book.

I would be happy if someone could comment on the other questions asked in the initial question.